# Error in export image from Google Earth Engine from Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to use the GEE Python API to export an image to Google Drive.
Everything works smooth, except the exporting stage.

```
boundary = ee.Feature(Countries.first()).geometry().bounds().getInfo()['coordinates']

task_config = {
    'fileNamePrefix': 'image',
    'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
    'scale': 500,
    'maxPixels': 10e15,
    'fileFormat': 'GeoTIFF',
    'skipEmptyTiles': True,
    'region': boundary ,
    'folder': 'myfolder'
    }

task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(image, str('image'), task_config)
task.start()
```

Where I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ee\batch.py", line 81, in start
    result = data.exportImage(self._request_id, self.config)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py", line 1126, in exportImage
    return startProcessing(request_id, params)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ee\deprecation.py", line 32, in Wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py", line 1100, in startProcessing
    return send_('/processingrequest', args)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py", line 1669, in send_
    raise ee_exception.EEException(json_content['error']['message'])
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Invalid request: 'driveFolder': Must be at most 255 characters.
```

It's like the parameter 'folder' was not read correctly, because in my Google Drive I then find an emtpy (since the task fails) folder named not after 'myfolder', as I specified, but after the long, entire list of parameters I specified in task_config. Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't test it, but I think the issue comes from parsing `task_config` as a dictionary. To keep your code without much modifications, just do:

```python
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(image, str('image'), **task_config)
```

the `**` will unpack the dict parsing it as keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
tera_prod = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
aqua_prod = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A1')

# get products for the daily

for i in range (len(hwp_18)-1):

    #print(hwp_18[i],hwp_18[i+1])
    modis_aqua = aqua_prod.filterDate(hwp_18[i],hwp_18[i+1])

    modis_tera = tera_prod.filterDate(hwp_18[i],hwp_18[i+1])

    #select the lst products
    aqua_day_lst = modis_aqua.select('LST_Day_1km').map(temp_conv)

    tera_day_lst = modis_tera.select('LST_Day_1km').map(temp_conv)


    aqua_night_lst = modis_aqua.select('LST_Night_1km').map(temp_conv)

    tera_night_lst = modis_tera.select('LST_Night_1km').map(temp_conv)


    #merge the corresponding products into one collection and convert to degree cel


    day_merge_deg = aqua_day_lst.merge(tera_day_lst)

    night_merge_deg = aqua_night_lst.merge(tera_night_lst)


    #make daily composites for day and night aqua and tera lst products

    day_comp = day_merge_deg.mean()

    night_comp = night_merge_deg.mean()

    #export images 

    task_config = {
        'region': estbound,
        'crs': 'EPSG:3301',
        'fileFormat': 'GeoTIFF',
        'fileNamePrefix': 'Day',
        'folder':'low',
        'image': day_comp,
        'description': str(hwp_18[i])
    }

    task=ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**task_config)
    task.start()

    print(i)

#GEE #python
```

I have this code after exporting the destination folder on google drive is empty. The code seems to work fine.