# Extracting data from GEE automatically

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to export my data to CSV files on Google Drive using this action:

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ndviFeatures,
  description: 'ndvi',
  selectors: ['ndvi'],
  folder: 'TRYING'
})
```

This action creates a task which I need to actively activate.
Is there a way for this thing to happen automatically?
I wish to run a for loop on several dates and change some parameters and have it all downloaded and separated into different files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if you run a script with the GEE Python api.
Take a look at the answer given here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219705/how-to-download-images-using-google-earth-engines-python-api

This is the way to export image (as .tiff) to your Google Drive acount with Python:

```
task = ee.batch.Export.image(image, description, config)
task.start()
```

Or maybe this is **better**:
[Error in export image from Google Earth Engine from Python API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326131/error-in-export-image-from-google-earth-engine-from-python-api)

```
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(image, str('image'), **task_config)
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you.
Any chance we can chat on WhatsApp? I am from Israel as well, I could use a bit of help. Won't take to much of your time.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible in the code editor. You always have to press `Run`.